# Python Django Translatable Log from Database with event and values as db columns

Tags: python, django

We are trying to develop a simple log for our website. It should be translatable though. What we have is the following model:

```
class AccountActivity(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(AccountDetails)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    event = models.TextField()
    values = models.TextField()

    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, editable=False)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    @property
    def message(self):
        message = _(self.event)
        return_message = message % self.values
        return return_message
```

When a user does something the following is executed:

```
def log_event(self, event_message, values):
        event = AccountActivity()
        event.user = self
        event.account = self.account_details
        event.event = event_message
        event.values = values
        event.save()
```

Sometimes it makes sense, that the event holds several placeholders for the format string such as:

```
"Group %s was deleted with the reason: %s"
```

The database saves the parameters as a tuple:

```
(u'TestGroup', u'This is just for testing purposes')
```

In another message that only holds one placeholder it saves the value as a normal string.

When these are printed out by using the `message` property, only the single value events are getting returned correctly, whereas the ones with the tuple cannot be displayed. (No error is thrown)

The template looks as follows:

```
{% for l in logs %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ l.message }}</td>
                <td>{{ l.createdAt }}</td>
                <td>{{ l.user.email }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

How is this possible? Python should recognise the tuple ? I am not sure how to approach this, parse the event and check how many params are expected and then declare the values as a tuple? Even though it is already saved as a tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `values` field is defined as a `models.TextField`, so it stores a string, never a tuple or anything else. For the example you gave, the database is storing the string `"(u'TestGroup', u'This is just for testing purposes')"`, which is the string representation of the tuple.

You need to [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the tuple (convert it to a string) to save it to the database, and deserialize it (convert the stored string back to a tuple) before using it to format the message. The following (untested) uses JSON as the serialization representation, although you can choose other approaches:

```
import simplejson as json

class AccountActivity(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def message(self):
        # Deserialization happens here
        values = json.loads(self.values)
        if isinstance(values, list):
            values = tuple(values)

        message = _(self.event)
        return_message = message % values
        return return_message

def log_event(self, event_message, values):
    event = AccountActivity()
    event.user = self
    event.account = self.account_details
    event.event = event_message
    event.values = json.dumps(values)  # serialization happens here
    event.save()
```

Be aware that JSON only deals with single value types such as strings, integers and lists/tuples (both stored as arrays – that's why I forced the conversion to `tuple` in the code above). If you need to store dates/times or other types, you may need to use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or other serialization library.